# 'Unresolved reference' errors for library functions being referenced in app module

Tags: java, android, module, architecture, kotlin

Example of usage:

```
package jfyg.etherscan.helloetherescan

import android.app.Application

class HelloEtherscanApplication : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        jfyg.ApiKey.takeOff.setApiKey("1234567891010dede") // <----
    }
}
```

The ApiKey class is a class i am calling from my `ewn` library module.  Even though I get no build errors, configure kotlin project says all kotlin files are configured, and I am able to reference the class by clicking and it takes me to the usage in the module.  When I build it tells me `Unresolved reference: ApiKey`  Please help me get to the bottom of this issue.

Dependencies in App Module:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    // google
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'

    // tests
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation project(':enw') //<-- importing module here
}
```

Dependencies in enw module(this is the library module):

```
  dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    /**
     Because RxAndroid releases are few and far between, it is recommended you also
     explicitly depend on RxJava's latest version for bug fixes and new features.
     */
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'

    // gson
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

    // retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'

    // kotlin
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    // tests
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Gradle Console:

```
  Putting task artifact state for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin' into context took 0.0 secs.
    file or directory '/Users/ackoneb/Android/etherscan/app/src/main/kotlin', not found
    file or directory '/Users/ackoneb/Android/etherscan/app/src/debug/kotlin', not found
    file or directory '/Users/ackoneb/Android/etherscan/app/libs', not found
    file or directory '/Users/ackoneb/Android/etherscan/app/src/main/kotlin', not found
    file or directory '/Users/ackoneb/Android/etherscan/app/src/debug/kotlin', not found
    Executing task ':app:compileDebugKotlin' (up-to-date check took 0.002 secs) due to:
      Task.upToDateWhen is false.
    All input files are considered out-of-date for incremental task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
    file or directory '/Users/ackoneb/Android/etherscan/app/src/main/kotlin', not found
    file or directory '/Users/ackoneb/Android/etherscan/app/src/debug/kotlin', not found
    file or directory '/Users/ackoneb/Android/etherscan/app/src/main/kotlin', not found
    file or directory '/Users/ackoneb/Android/etherscan/app/src/debug/kotlin', not found
    file or directory '/Users/ackoneb/Android/etherscan/app/libs', not found
    file or directory '/Users/ackoneb/Android/etherscan/app/libs', not found
    Using Kotlin incremental compilation

    e: /Users/ackoneb/Android/etherscan/app/src/main/java/jfyg/etherscan/helloetherescan/HelloEtherscanApplication.kt: (8, 22): Unresolved reference: ApiKey
    e: /Users/ackoneb/Android/etherscan/app/src/main/java/jfyg/etherscan/helloetherescan/MainActivity.kt: (5, 21): Unresolved reference: ethereum
    e: /Users/ackoneb/Android/etherscan/app/src/main/java/jfyg/etherscan/helloetherescan/MainActivity.kt: (11, 24): Unresolved reference: EthereumStat

    [KOTLIN] deleting /Users/ackoneb/Android/etherscan/app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug on error
    [KOTLIN] deleting /Users/ackoneb/Android/etherscan/app/build/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug on error
    :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
    :app:compileDebugKotlin (Thread[Task worker for ':',5,main]) completed. Took 0.31 secs.

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
    > Compilation error. See log for more details
```

Comment: In which package are the declarations located in the `enw` module? There's no `import` statements In your usage example.

Comment: I actually Inlined my import in that HelloEtherscanApplication class.

[import jfyg.class.ApiKey]

Comment: As far as I can tell, valid package names cannot contain a segment `class`, which is a keyword in Kotlin. Can you check if renaming the package helps?

Comment: the real package name isn't class. I changed a few names while writing this question.  Sorry for making it confusing there.

Comment: issue is still unresolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be you are not importing the library. 
Your post says I am importing my library `ewn` but then you include:

```
implementation project(':enw')
```

So... Which one should it be?

`implementation project(':ewn')` ?

After getting that right, I would recommend `./gradlew clean` followed by a `./gradlew build` and in a case where that doesn't work Restart Android Studio and Invalidate your cache (can be found in the File menu on mac).

Good Luck and Happy Coding!

Comment: I have matched the names.. and i'm still getting the same error.  That ewn happened to be an error while writing this question. Sorry for my sloppiness, and thanks for your response.

Comment: have you tried deleting the build directory, cleaning, and rebuilding?

Comment: Cleaning,deleting,and rebuilding didn't work.  However,  I decided to create a new module and just test it by returning a string, then I dragged my classes from my previous module to the new module and it worked.  I'm not sure what the issue was with the previous module, but the solution for me was drag my classes into a new module. I could only conclude that it was an IDE issue.

Comment: perhaps, the module was not actually linked in the settings.xml file?

Comment: that's a possibillity, or maybe it was linked incorrectly.